# How to stream video over Socket Class (or XMLSocket) with ActionScript?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, sockets, video

**How to stream video over Socket Class (or XMLSocket) with ActionScript?**

---

or\and

---

**How to do it using Socket Class (or XMLSocket) in AIR?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you looking to stream video using Socket? The performance would be far, far less than what's offered by Adobe's built-in classes for this.

To stream audio and video in Flash, you'll need an FMS-alike server. [Red5](http://www.red5.org/) is an open-source server that allows this (like Maciek said). However, serving your own live video over [flash.net.Socket](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/Socket.html) and then decoding it yourself would yield horrible performance. Essentially, the only way to stream video in performance-acceptable way would be to use 
[flash.net.NetConnection](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/NetConnection.html). This uses the [RTMP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol) for media streaming.

Also, if it's not live streaming of video you are looking for, take look at serving those video files over a normal HTTP server and the [FLV format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Video).

Comment: The point is not in performance. I just need to stream live video using Sockets. Let's suppose I have super-fast computer and a web camera. But only thing I can use to send video from that camera is SOCKET connection!( I know that I can just take Byte Arrays From current video object bitmap data but that will give me frame by frame representation of video stream... I want something else, better, faster.

Answer (score 1):

I think You can only use sockets in Air. If You need streaming in Flex/Flash look for RED5 RTMP server, there are client and server examples.

Comment: Ok so how to do it using Socket Class (or XMLSocket) in AIR?

Answer (score 1):

Can't use Socket class for this -- you don't have a framebuffer to the webcam.

You could use [Adobe Stratus](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/stratus/) for this -- it's a peer to peer negotiation layer that supports hooking Camera and Microphone up to a (peer to peer) NetStream.