# Stream Video and Audio in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

i am new to flex. I have this task. My boss wants an application that will enable his secretary in another room listen and view and probably take minutes of his meeting in the conference room. There is a webcam attached to one of the computers in the conference room.

Please i need help here, i will be so grateful if one will be provided. A colleague told me that flex can do this. But i don't know how.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), and [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have struggled with the exactly same requirement few months back. So I can understand how surprising it is for a new comer like u. See [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8445297/how-to-transmit-live-video-over-a-socket-using-flex-actionscript-3) I asked few months back.

What  I can tell from my experience is that their is no straight forward way for your task however it is achievable with some simple tweaks. As suggested by @rajesh You can capture the live video using some media server (i.e. Flash and than send it to other side. You can also record AV data by your self and then send it using [Socket communication](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=17_Networking_and_communications_5.html).

Have a look on [Red5](http://www.red5-recorder.com/) site. It explains lots of things. Let me know about your progress in this task, so that I can learn from as well as help you. Enjoy :)